# JQuery serialize is not working

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to serialize the data in my form but it's not working.

`manage-user-form` is the id of the form.

```
$('#manage-user-form').live('submit',function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var firstname = $("#firstName").val();
  var lastname = $("#lastName").val();

  // this doesn't work
  alert($(this).serialize())

  // this doesn't work
  var d = $('#manage-user-form').find('input,select,textarea').serialize();
  alert(d);

  // this does work
  alert(firstname);
  alert(lastname);
});
```

Comment: You should be using .on instead of .live

Comment: Another "not working" question? Come on, you can do better than this. Look at Help on this site and learn how to ask a question. "Not working" is not a problem description. Should we guess the error and intended/real behavior?

Comment: I'm on 1.3 so no `on` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try following working code :

```
// Get the form data. This serializes the entire form. pritty easy huh!
var form = new FormData($('#form_step4')[0]);
form.append('view_type','addtemplate');
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "savedata.php",
    data: form,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success:  function(data){
        //alert("---"+data);
        alert("Settings has been updated successfully.");
        window.location.reload(true);
    }
});
```

it will transfer all form data to savedata.php in above case.

Comment: SKV, can I see the serialized data? If so, how?

Comment: can you tell me what are to trying to do so i can provide a better ans ?

Comment: All I want to do is to serialize my form. That's it

Comment: var form = new FormData($('#form_step4')[0]); is doing the same and passing it to savedata.php for further processing for ex : ajax logging in..

Comment: OK. If I use the console.log, shouldn't I see a serialized string? I don't see any of my values or keys. What I see is, `FormData { append=append()}`... which is much more than I'm used to seeing from this thing

Comment: i am afraid as FormData creates an jQuery object, if you want to view or alert the data appended before sending it to processing you need to use serialize only.. ex : http://api.jquery.com/serialize/ else using formData you can check your form data by echoing it on savedata.php as in above code and alert it from response i.e in success function

Comment: Thanks again, SKV. Do I also need the `form.append` line in there as well?

Comment: no form append only add additional parameter as in the code above it will add view_type = template while sending data.

Comment: Thanks again SKV. I just sent over the results of `form` and even after I fill in the form, I get an empty array on the server side